# How to add the pan tool within the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pan

i just want to add a pan tool within the " iframe " ,
and i tried by [this demo](http://rob--w.github.io/grab-to-pan.js/demo.html)
but I can't able to make a pan tool within the iframe.
can anyone give any suggestions regarding this?

```js
document.getElementById('activate-g2p').onchange = function () {
    if (this.checked) g2p.activate();
    else g2p.deactivate();
};

var scrollableContainer = document.getElementById('scrollable-container');
var g2p = new GrabToPan({
    element: scrollableContainer, // required
    onActiveChanged: function (isActive) { // optional
        if (window.console) { // IE doesn't define console unless the devtools are open
            console.log('Grab-to-pan is ' + (isActive ? 'activated' : 'deactivated'));
        }
    }
});

g2p.activate();
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.filler {
  width: 200%;
  font-size: 100px;
  /* I don't want to type a huge wall of Lorem ipsum */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://rob--w.github.io/grab-to-pan.js/grab-to-pan.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://rob--w.github.io/grab-to-pan.js/grab-to-pan.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="activate-g2p" checked> Activate Grab to Pan</label>
<div class="scrollable" id="scrollable-container">
  <div class="filler">
    Grab to pan - Grab this section with your mouse, and move your mouse around to pan the content.
  </div>
</div>
```

here I want to add one iframe ex:www.w3schools.com
and under this link, I need a pan tool(hand).

Thank you

Comment: where is your code that you have integrated the pan?

Comment: thank you,above html file how can i add iframe and it has to be pan tool

Comment: It works for me already ? : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nx7B.gif